# Making a page show up better on google

Tags: seo, metadata, search-engine, meta-tags

Hey i have a website that has been going for a while but it has no Meta data set in it. I have added some meta data like language, description, keywords and a title.

The thing i want to know is when would google change its records of that site and start ranking the page better?

Does anyone know any helpful guides or anything like that that explain this? Any other search engine optimisation tips would be very welcome as well.

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some Google SEO Guideline...

[Webmaster Guideline for seo](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769)
[Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)
[Googlewebmastercentral](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/)
[Google SEO guideline](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291)